# AVFoundation Camera Captured Zoom Photo issue

Tags: ios, camera, avfoundation, ios9, uipinchgesturerecognizer

Below i have pasted code for zoom module.the zoom also works little slugish and the result image for captured photo is not according to zoom i.e the result image is slightly zoom-in.Can someone guide me.Thanks

```
func pinchToZoom(sender:UIPinchGestureRecognizer){

    if(sender.state == .Began){
        scale = sender.scale
    }

    if(sender.state == .Began || sender.state == .Changed){

        //NEW
        var effectiveScale = scale * sender.scale
        if(effectiveScale < 1.0){
            effectiveScale = 1.0
        }
        let maxScale = self.imageOutput.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo).videoMaxScaleAndCropFactor

        if(effectiveScale > maxScale){
            effectiveScale = maxScale
        }

        //Transform
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(0.25)
        let transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(effectiveScale, effectiveScale)
        cameraView.transform = transform
        CATransaction.commit()

        scale = sender.scale // Store the previous scale factor for the next pinch gesture call

        do {
            try device.lockForConfiguration()
            device.videoZoomFactor = effectiveScale
            device.unlockForConfiguration()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```